# all my website links is lables as Indexed, not submitted in sitemap in google search console

Tags: seo, wordpress, sitemap, yoast

I have a weird problem with my WordPress website and I am using Yoast plugin with my SEO .. after submitting my sitemap inside my google search console and the status of the sitemap is Success .. I tried to test my links by URL inspection and no matter which link I test form the links inside my sitemap the result of Coverage is Indexed, not submitted in sitemap it means that google search console can't find my link inside the sitemap but iam sure that all my links are inside the sitemap even when i try to test my home page it gives the same result Indexed, not submitted in sitemap can anyone help me fix this problem my ranking is going down every day

Comment: my question is not duplicate you didn't understand what I mean ...
a sitemap is submitted to my google search console and iam sure of it but when it tries to use the URL inspection for my home page it says it's indexed but not submitted to the sitemap .. how is it possible? if the home page URL is included in my submitted sitemap the result suld be indexed and submitted to the sitemap